# A trouble with Django loaddata command

Tags: django, django-models

I am writing some free software based on Django.

I have a class `Item` which describes a pricing plan (such as "subscription, $10 per week without a trial period").

My code often creates new items based on existing. For example new item created based on the above item would be: "subscription, $10 per week with the trial period 10 days" (for the case if a customer paid for 10 days already).

Now there are two kinds of items:

- predefined items (as in the first example);
- modified items (based on another item, as in the second example).

Now the trouble:

- I create predefined items using `./manage.py loaddata ...` command which loads the items from a JSON file.
- I create modified items in my Python code.
- If I add a new item to the JSON code and run `./manage.py loaddata ...` again, then (accordingly to how I understand) the `loaddata` command may overwrite one of the modified items (created later by my Python code).

What to do to avoid overwriting modified items with new predefined items? More generally, how to keep predefined and modified items distinct, to be sure the code could differentiate which items are predefined and which are not?

Comment: To prevent overwriting instances, you should have a unique primary key for each entry. It could be a integer, or some other guaranteed unique field. Read the django docs on "Serializing Django objects" (the implementation of `loaddata` is not very complicated, and in many cases, it's simpler to just as easy to write your own management command or task to load data). `loaddata` is primarily meant for loading data created with the corresponding `dumpdata` management command. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/

Comment: @HåkenLid To used UUIDs is an idea. But is there a better (e.g. more efficient) way?

Comment: Depends on what data you have. Sometime there is some obvious natural key. Countries have ISO country codes, for example. Django's default is to use an incrementing sequence of integers. UUID are also well suited to use as primary keys. Just make sure you only create a UUID once for each entry, so if you want to import the same data again, you don't end up with a bunch of duplicates with new UUIDs. The main disadvantage with UUIDs is that they are a bit too long to remember for us  humans, so not ideal if you need manual entry. Imagine using a UUID as a bank account number or email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First declare an abstract model:

```
class ItemBase(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # ...
```

Then declare:

```
class PredefinedItem(ItemBase):
     pass

class ModifiedItem(ItemBase):
    base = models.OneToOneField(PredefinedItem, null=True)

    @atomic
    @staticmethod
    def obtain_predefined(id):
        try:
           return ModifiedItem.objects.get(base_id=id)
        except ModifiedItem.DoesNotExist:
            predefined = PredefinedItem.objects.get(pk=id)
            return ModifiedItem.objects.create(base=id, **model_to_dict(
                predefined,
                fields=[f.name for f in ItemBase._meta.fields]))
```

`obtain_predefined()` allows to make a copy of a predefined object, of this copy to be used instead of the predefined object itself. Thus we can not worry about predefined object overwriting modified objects.

Note: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52787554/856090 answer used.

Comment: Ugh, this solution won't work if there are other models (such as a derived model) referring to `PredefinedItem`. After copying it will refer to the `PredefinedItem` not to `ModifiedItem` as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Dumpdata and Loaddata should not be used to create "modified items". Maybe treat these commands more like "backup" and "restore". If you want to load new created items from a json file, write a custom management command:

[Custom Management Commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/#management-commands-and-locales)

Comment: I know that `loaddata` should not be used to create "modified items". (I call them "modified" because they are created using my Python code, not `loaddata`.) You told me nothing new. Please delete your answer, because it does not address the issues raised in my question.