# Copy all fields of a class derived from an abstract model (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models `A` and `B` of the same structure derived from the same abstract model:

```
class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # ...  # more fields

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class A(CommonInfo):
    pass

class B(CommonInfo):
    pass
```

Now having an object of class `A`, I want to create an object of class `B` with the same values of fields.

What is the proper Django way to copy all fields of one object to the other?

The only way I know is to enumerate all fields (by the way, how to do it?) of an object and store them in the other object. But is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `model_to_dict(..)` and use this dictionary in the construction of a `B` object, like:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

my_b = B(**model_to_dict(
    my_a,
    fields=[f.name for f in CommonInfo._meta.fields],
))
#  some processing
my_b.save()
```

Note that if the `CommonInfo` contains foreign keys to objects, then these *references* will be copied, but no new referred objects will be constructed. Furthermore this will *not* work for many-to-many fields, so you need to exclude these (and add the related objects later).